# LINQ Join and performing aggregate functions

Tags: linq

I am facing issue in writing LINQ query to perform join on three tables and then performing aggregate functions on the rows. Kindly do provide some help.

I have three tables

**Table 1:** Students (Id, Name)

**Table 2:** Subject (SubID, Title, Id)

**Table 3:** Grade (Id, SubID, marks)

I have to write LINQ query to get the results as following

> Count of Students table rows
>   Count of Grade table rows
>   Sum of
>   marks of all rows in Grade table

I am writing query as following but it is not up to the mark as i feel it is not correct.

```
var _Count = from student in _context.Students 
join subject in _context.Subject  on student.Id equals subject.Id
join grade in _context.Grade on subject.SubID equals grade.SubID
// How to group them?
select new { //How to take and return the counts?};
```

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea

Comment: Thanks, i will try find an example.

Comment: If i understand you correctly...

    `var countOfStudents = _context.Students.Count();
    var countOfSubjects = _context.Subject.Distinct().Count();
    var sumOfMarks = _context.Grade.Sum(x=>x.Marks);`

Comment: How can we get it done in Join and not as three seprate queries?

Comment: We can do it in a single query, but you need to provide more details, for example: input data and expected output.

Comment: Sorry but i did not understand when you say more details. I have mentioned all data (not actual table names) in my question. Kindly have a look.